# 2 JSP use same class(Old class)

Tags: java, jsp

I try to write 2 jsp that call the same class, but I can't do that. It look like I have create a new object for each jsp.

```
<!--First jsp-->
<body>
<%
    int i =9;
    TestClass objectjsp = new TestClass();
    objectjsp.Plusinteger(i);
    out.print("First jsp Interger is :"+objectjsp.ReturnInterger());    
%>
    <br>
    <a href="Second.jsp?a=y">GO Next JSP</a>
</body>

<!--Second jsp-->
<body>
<%
    int j =5;
    TestClass objectjsp = new TestClass();
    objectjsp.Plusinteger(j);
    out.print("Secnd Jsp Interger is :"+objectjsp.ReturnInterger());
    objectjsp.PrintInterger();
%>
<!--  -->
</body>
```

Class that I used

```
package ScruitPackage;

public class TestClass {
    int integer =0;
    public void Plusinteger(int input)
    {
        integer = integer+input;
    }
    public int ReturnInterger()
    {
        return integer;
    }
    public void PrintInterger()
    {
        System.out.print(integer);
    }
}
```

So the result after I run First jsp is 
First jsp Interger is :9 
and then I go the Second jsp via ahref(GO Next JSP) and result is
Secnd Jsp Interger is :5

My question

1. How to make the result be 14(9+5)
   I know that TestClass objectjsp = new TestClass(); in Second jsp is wrong, but I don't know how to call old class.
2. How to print text inside PrintInterger() (Is it possible?)

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use **session** or **request parameters**

---

## using session

Session is a "location" reserved to store information between calls.
When you go from one jsp to another one, the web server loses all information and your class is lost (because of the stateless nature of Servlets).

You can read more here: https://www.javatpoint.com/http-session-in-session-tracking

Inside the First.jsp include this code:

```
    request.getSession().setAttribute("firstValue", i);
```

Inside the Second.jsp include this code:

```
int i = (Integer)request.getSession().getAttribute("firstValue");
objectjsp.Plusinteger(i);
```

In the Second.jsp now you'll have **objectjsp.Plusinteger(i);** and **objectjsp.Plusinteger(j);**

I did an example storing the integer **i** but in another scenario you can store the **TestClass** instance, for example:

```
request.getSession().setAttribute("testClass", objectjsp);
```

and

```
objectjsp = (TestClass)request.getSession().getAttribute("testClass");
```

---

## using request parameters:

Request parameters is a way to pass information to a jsp when calling it.

In First.jsp change only the line where you call your Second.jsp

```
<!--First jsp-->
<body>
<%
    int i =9;
    TestClass objectjsp = new TestClass();
    objectjsp.Plusinteger(i);
    out.print("First jsp Interger is :"+objectjsp.ReturnInterger());    
%>
    <br>
    <a href="second.jsp?i=<%=i%>">GO Next JSP</a>
</body>
```

In Second.jsp only add a line to get the request parameter and after use Plusinteger method.

```
<!--Second jsp-->
<body>
<%
    int j =5;
    int i = Integer.valueOf(request.getParameter("i"));
    TestClass objectjsp = new TestClass();
    objectjsp.Plusinteger(i);
    objectjsp.Plusinteger(j);
    out.print("Secnd Jsp Interger is :"+objectjsp.ReturnInterger());
    objectjsp.PrintInterger();
%>
<!--  -->
</body>
```

---

## Observation

Try to use the Java Convention.
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html
Try to avoid names like integer for variables, because integer is a reserved word in many languages.

Comment: This really helpful !! Thank you so much